# Question based on first digit of $2^m$ in base $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Definition*

Let $x$ be given positive integer, function $f(x)$ shows first digit of $x$ from left side in base $3$.

*Example* Let $x=47=(1202)_3$ so $f(47)=1$.

> Question, show that
>
> For integer $m$, if $f(2^m)=2$ then $f(2^{m-1})=f(2^{m+1})=1$ ?

Source code

```
m=1
while m <1000:
    n2=2**m
    rem_array = []
    while n2 != 0:
        mod = n2%3
        if mod != 0:
          rem = mod
          n2 = n2 - rem
          rem_array.append(round(rem))
          n2=n2/3
        else:
            n2 = n2/3
            rem_array.append(0)
    print("\n",m,rem_array[-1])
    m = m+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for any given $m \ge 1$ you have

$$f(2^m) = 2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note for any positive integer $n$ and for any base $b$, having the left most digit being $d$ means there's an integer $j \ge 0$ such that

$$d(b^j) \le n \lt (d+1)(b^{j}) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means that, for some integer $k \ge 0$,

$$2(3^k) \le 2^m \lt 3(3^k) = 3^{k+1} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Dividing through by $2$ gives

$$3^k \le 2^{m - 1} \lt \frac{3^{k+1}}{2} = (1.5)3^k \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This shows that $f(2^{m-1}) = 1$. Next, multiplying \eqref{eq3A} by $2$ gives

$$4(3^k) = \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)3^{k+1} \le 2^{m+1} \lt 2(3^{k+1}) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This shows that, also, $f(2^{m+1}) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The leading digit of $2^m$ base $3$ is determined by the fractional part of $m\log_3(2)$, denoted $\{m\log_3(2)\}$. It falls in $[0,\log_3(2))$ if and only if that leading digit is $1$. It falls in $[\log_3(2),1)$ if and only if that leading digit is $2$.

If $f(2^m)=2$, then $\{m\log_3(2)\}$ is in $[\log_3(2),1)\approx[0.63,1)$. Letting $m\to m+1$, you add $\log_3(2)$ prior to taking the fractional part. So $\{(m+1)\log_3(2)\}$ is in $\approx[0.26,0.63)$, and so $f(2^{m+1})=1$.

Letting $m\to m-1$, you subtract $\log_3(2)$ prior to taking the fractional part. So $\{(m-1)\log_3(2)\}$ is in $\approx[0,0.37)$, and so $f(2^{m-1})=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just do it.

If $f(2^m) = 2$ then $2*3^k < 2^m < 3^{k+1} - 1$ for some $k$.

Divide everything by $2$ and we ge $3^k < 2^{m-1} < \frac {3^{k+1}-1}2 < \frac 32 3^k < 2*3^k$ so $f(2^{m-1}) = 1$.

Multiply everything by $2$ and we get

$4*3^k = 3^{k+1} + 3^k < 2^{m+1} < 2*3^{k+1}-1 < 2*3^{k+1}$ so $f(2^{m+1}) = 1$.